# Versioning of documents

Tags: document-library, versioning, approval-process, content-approval

I was working on the approval process of a SharePoint document. I did the following:

- Check out the document
- Make necessary changes to the document
- Check-in the document as a Minor version (draft) 3.1
- Submit for approval
- Approved

Once approved, the version of the document changed to 4.0 instead of 3.1, means it published as a major version.

Is there any way that the published version still in the minor version?

Much appreciated for the suggestions and help.

Comment: When document is approved, next major version of document will be published. Do you want to continue using minor version instead of major version?

Comment: Yes, after the document is approved, need the document still in the minor version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done using SharePoint's built-in approval functionality. If you wanted something like this, you'd need to build something custom.

I haven't tried to do so but I **think** it could be done using Power Automate. The one issue that immediately comes to mind is, what happens when a user creates new minor versions while a previous minor version is awaiting approval? For example, what if an approver rejects 3.1 when the current minor version is 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

As Rob said, this cannot be done as approved version (internal field name "_moderationstatus") imply version is majoir (.0).

What you can do is to manage a custom status field with choices Approved/Rejected and change by the means of a workflow task this custum status in Approved.

I did something similar for a customer, however this status is still for a draft version, and this imply all consequences of a draft (depending by library setting, draft version imght be not visible to other users)

Hope this help...